# What protocols that routers can use show the vendor and model?

Tags: router

Are there any router protocols that shows the vendor and model details to others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually depends on the router and model.

Cisco routers can use CDP (also LLDP) if it is configured to do so, but that is only for the specific link.

Some routers can use LLDP, but, again, that is only a link protocol.

Many routers can be configured for SNMP, and they may have MIBs that reveal that information.